# Is ASLR useless in preventing attacks such as return-to-libc in linux?

Tags: linux, aslr, glibc

If i'm correct, due ASLR we load libc into some random address. And then in order to make that happen without allowing write permissions of text pages within memory we use plt/got. Now I can simply jump back into some libc@plt function that is well-known before execution of the program and pretty much bypass it. So does return-to-plt make the entire concept useless?

Answer (score 12):

**Yes, if PIE is disabled.** It is often said that ASLR's effectiveness is [significantly reduced](https://securityetalii.es/2013/02/03/how-effective-is-aslr-on-linux-systems/) for applications which are not compiled with PIE (Position Independent Code) support. When PIE is not used, the program [must rely on a fixed PLT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24984955/9782169), created during linking, to resolve the addresses of functions in shared libraries. When ASLR is used and PIE is enabled, code-reuse attacks in general are mitigated, though infoleaks are still so ubiquitous that ASLR can often be defeated with [side-channel attacks](https://www.cs.ucr.edu/%7Enael/pubs/micro16.pdf), making it close to useless against local malicious code and limiting its effectiveness to attacks over the network and [scriptless exploits](https://scarybeastsecurity.blogspot.com/2016/11/0day-exploit-advancing-exploitation.html). There are several other reasons ASLR without PIE is weaker and why less randomization is used, as [explained in another answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/41715/106285).

Answer (score 4):

return to plt and return to libc are slightly different attacks.

**Return to libc**

One of the ways to prevent buffer overflow is to use a non executable stack. To make non executable stack, from CPU & system level they use something called NX bit. If NX bit is set, that memory address is non executable. Even if we perform a buffer overflow and over write the stack to redirect the return pointer to stack where our shell code resides, the shell code wouldn't run because it would be in stack - which is a non-executable memory section.

This is when we use return to libc attack to spawn a shell. Instead of using the classic approach to overwrite the return address to the address of shell code, we use the address of libc system() call.

**Return to PLT**

ASLR or address space layout randomization is another method to control buffer overflows. Like I said in the previous section, people bypass NX by finding executables loaded on to memory by system.like libc. This was possible because it was easy to identify the location of system loaded executables. ASLR randomised the address of these executables and thus reduced the probability of spawning a shell by redirecting to them.

The reason why this attack is possible is that in executables with dynamically linked libraries the libc function address can be obtained from PLT and GOT. PLT address is not randomised and that's makes the attack easy.

Comment: you're saying a lot here but you're basically saying nothing lol

Comment: return to PLT makes that attack possible. But that's required for dynamically linking libraries to an executabel

Comment: Forgive me if I am making it ambiguous. Please read the following https://sploitfun.wordpress.com/2015/05/08/bypassing-aslr-part-i/

Comment: firstly my question wasn't what buffer overflow is or how to exploit buffer overflows or what nx bit is, thank you for telling me things I already know however, 
my question was simple - as using plt means you're using fixed addresses that are known prior to execution - ASLR becomes useless - randomizing the address libc is loaded into in order to prevent return to libc attacks, I'm looking for someone to explain to me if I got that part wrong, stick to this question please

Comment: I know that blog, blog post I don't need an explanation of what aslr or nx bit are

Comment: First of all you got the concept wrong in the question itself. That's why I had to explain why return to libc and return to PLT are different. 1. When you use ASLR the libc functions are loaded in random addresses. But the offset of libc functions from the libc base address is not changed. In other words the order of libc functions are not altered. 2. PLT is the guessable address here. PLT is guessable and PLT points to the libc address. Since PLT is not randomised the randomisation of libc executable address is rendered useless

Comment: In short, yes return to PLT makes everything useless. But that's the bare minimum for dynamically linking libraries and that's explained in the blog post. That's why I gave you that link in the first place :)

Comment: lol why have I got the concept wrong?, as an attaker I could overrun some buffer into the address of a prior known libc function if no ASLR is used (return-to-libc) and if it is used I could just overrun the return address to be system@plt which should be guessable / known prior to execution, what's the difference? both are taking advantages of ROP